# How to click google first link selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to visit the first link using this code but it does not work, why?

````
from gettext import find
from tkinter import Button
from xml.dom.minidom import Element
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

kaupunki = "Helsinki"

PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

accept = driver.find_element("xpath" , '//*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div')
time.sleep(2)
accept.click()

searching = driver.find_element("name", 'q')

searching.send_keys("airbnb ",kaupunki)
time.sleep(0.2)

searching.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element("tag name", "h3").click()```

Output is
````

c:\Users\sachi\seleniummm.py:13: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated,

```
how can I fix this and get this working? I have checked other posts but it tells me to do the same. But I am not sure why this is not working.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Path` is now deprecated, so that `Service` is used instead.
So, instead of

```py
PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Try the following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

webdriver_service = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
```

Comment: but still it does not click the first link

Comment: You asked about the `c:\Users\sachi\seleniummm.py:13: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated` message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Service:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

PATH= "C:\Program Files (x86)\selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH))
```

Comment: but the click now does not work